# How to make a 3d line in holoviews library?

Tags: python, plot, holoviews

I have two sets of 3d trajectory data that I need to plot. The first trajectory needs to be as a 3d scatter plot - which can be done using the 
Scatter3D functionality. The second trajectory needs to be a continuous line. Despite searching on the documentation page and the web I've not been able to find it.

Could someone please let me know if it is possible at all ?

My first SO question here , sorry in advance for not sticking to convention...

Comment: Currently there is no Line3D element in HoloViews, but if you file a feature request one could be added pretty easily.

Comment: Thanks @philippjfr ! Will do!

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of the HoloViews library has the 3D line functionality - the `Path3D` function.

As shown in their [docs](http://holoviews.org/reference/elements/plotly/Path3D.html) example:

```
line = np.random.randn(500, 3).cumsum(axis=0)
path = hv.Path3D(line)

path
```